# EloquentJavaScript - Referencing by this keyword not working?

Tags: javascript, this

I want to be sure, http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html, example:

```
    (function(exports) {
      var names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
                   "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

      exports.name = function(number) {
        return names[number];
      };
      exports.number = function(name) {
        return names.indexOf(name);
      };
    })(this.weekDay = {});

    console.log(weekDay.name(weekDay.number("Saturday")));
    // → weekDay not defined
```

It works when i run it on mentioned website, but when i try to do the same in vs code (+ node.js to debug) it says that `weekDay` is not defined. I have figured it out that the cause of this is that this keyword is not refering to object that holds the whole code, but it refers to the object that holds object that is calling the function, so i have tried this:

```
(function(exports) {
    var names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
                 "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

    exports.name = function(number) {
      return names[number];
    };
    exports.number = function(name) {
      return names.indexOf(name);
    };
  })(weekDay = {});

  console.log(weekDay.name(weekDay.number("Saturday")));
// → Saturday
```

And it works, can anyone explain why? IMO passed argument is not treated as function variable, but variable that belongs to object that calls the function (but why the code from book works on website then then?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, don't feel bad about not understanding `this`. It's confusing.

This sums `this` up pretty well:

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md#review-tldr

Props to sensei Kyle.

My TL;DR: the `this` you're calling in node is bound to the code running in the file.  The `this` you're calling in the browser is bound to the `window` object which is a special object available in a browser with superpowers left over from ages past. ;)

Remember `this` is a binding, made when a function is invoked and what it references is entirely dependent on the call-site where the function is called.

In the example sandbox (called from the browser's global scope), `this` refers to the browser's `window` object. `window` is the browser's global object. It contains all the global variables. Your call-site is the global scope.

In the simplest terms, each node file runs in its own bubble. Each file has its own `this` and the call-site is the bubble. Your variables in the global scope will not automagically be hanging out under `this` in a node module.

One more plug: read Kyle's books. Go take a class from him. He's an amazing teacher.